# Pattern matching text in a file?

Tags: python, pattern-matching

I have an input file that looks as follows 
[input file link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/045nT.png)

and need to create an output file that looks like this
[output file link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5c3nf.png)

I started with this but the error handling and pattern matching is messing up the logic (specially the occurrences of : in URL as well as the data). Also, the average in output file is average across the non zero or non null values

```
with open("input.txt") as f:
 next(f) # skips header
 for line in f:

  cleanline = re.sub('::',':',line) # handles the two :: case
  newline = re.split("[\t:]",cleanline) #splits on either tab or :
  print newline
  x=0
  total=0
    for i in range(3,7):
     if newline[i] <> 0 or newline[i] != None:
      x+=1
      total+=total
      avg=total/x
      print avg
```

Comment: I'd suggest using the `csv` module to read and write the files. It can handle a lot of the special case for your. Also suggest you [edit] your question and show a long example of an input file with all the special cases in it along with what the expected output should look like.

Comment: I added images of input and output file to explain what i am trying to do better. thanks for suggesting that. the post was too confusing

Comment: Actually what I meant was for you to cut lines from both files and paste them into your question (indented by 4 spaces). That way someone could use the first to be able to run you code, and the second to check results.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you approach this from a different angle. First, split each line along the tabs and then validate each entry individually. This allows you to compile a regular expression for each entry and compile more precise error messages. A nice way to do this is with tuple unpacking and the split method:

```
from __future__ import print_function

with open("input.txt") as in_file, open("output.txt", 'w') as out_file:
    next(in_file) # skips header

    for line in in_file:
        error_message = []
        # remove line break character and split along the tabs
        id_and_date, user_id, p1, p2, p3, p4, url = line.strip("\n").split("\t")

        # split the first entry at the first :
        split_id_date = id_and_date.split(":", 1)
        if len(split_id_date) == 2:
            order_id, date = split_id_date
        elif len(split_id_date) == 1:
            # assume this is the order id
            # or do something 
            order_id, date = (split_id_date[0], "")
            error_message.append("Invalid Date") 
        else:
            # set default values if nothing is present
            order_id, date = ("", "")
        # validate order_id and date here using re.match
        # add errors to error_message list:
        # error_message.append("Invalid Date") 

        # calculate average price
        # first, compile a list of the non-zero prices
        nonzero_prices = [int(x) for x in (p1, p2, p3, p4) if int(x) > 0] # this can be done more efficient
        # compute the average price
        avg_price = sum(nonzero_prices) / len(nonzero_prices)

        # validate url using re here
        # handle errors as above

        print("\t".join([order_id, date, user_id, str(avg_price), url, ", ".join(error_message)]), file=out_file)
```

I did not add the `re` calls to validate the entries, as I do not know what exactly you expect to see in the entries. However, I added a comment where the call to `re.match` or something similar would be reasonable.

I hope this helps.